# TTF font for LEGO bricks

Tags: storage

I'm in the process of reprinting labels for the zillions of LEGO storage drawers in Junior's toy room.

I'm not looking for a font that depicts Latin alphabet characters seemingly built out of LEGO bricks, but instead a font which code points map to drawings of LEGO bricks, plates and tiles. Similar to windings, but with LEGO part shapes instead of smileys.

I believe there is at least one font where letters are actually LEGO parts. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you'd like a typeface that displays certain characters such as 'B', '4', or '$' as icons representing different bricks? I think it may be easier to resize images of bricks to fit your labels.

Comment: Yes @Ambo100. This is exactly what I mean. In which case printing labels is just a matter of using a character map in a text processor.  That said, I can't seem to find it. I Might have dreamed it...

Answer (score 4):

I searched around on dafont.com, fonts.com, and myfonts.com but didn't find anything.  However, I found [this post](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=21527) on the eurobricks.com forum from 2008, which links to this page:

http://www.house42.com/2008/09/17/legorama-fontstruct-font/

This font (and its variants) are all available for download as TTFs (free account registration required):

- [Legorama](http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/99103)
- [Legorama Fill](http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/99748)
- [Legorama Everywhere](http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/98535)
- [Legorama Everywhere Fill](http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/99147)

The fonts are available under the [CC BY-NC-ND 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/) license (Attribution required, non-commercial use, no derivative works).

Alternatively, if you're feeling really ambitious, here's a tutorial on [how to make a LEGO font yourself](http://www.vectordiary.com/illustrator/lego-bricks-typeface-tutorial/).

Comment: Dave, Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I was not clear enough. I'm not looking for a font that depicts Latin alphabet characters seemingly built out of LEGO bricks, but instead a font which code points map to drawings of LEGO bricks, plates and tiles. Similar to windings, but with LEGO part shapes instead of smileys.  I actually came across the various links you cite before posting my question.

Comment: @AlainPannetier *aha* that makes sense. I'll google around some more.